# Как средствами jQuery задать div-ам, объединенным в группу другим div-ом, максимальную из их высот ?

Tags: jquery, html, css

Здравствуйте! Есть такой повторяющийся фрагмент *html* кода:

```
 <div class="row">
     <div class="item"></div>
     <div class="item"></div>
     <div class="item"></div>
     <div class="clear"></div>    
 </div>
```

Эта структура может представляться в двух вариантах - таблица и строки, соответствующий переключатель уже реализован.

Нужно выровнять высоту ***item*** только для вида "таблица", когда они представлены как столбцы и сбросить в *auto* при переключении в режим "строки", что бы у каждого ***item*** была своя высота (иначе между строками будут лишние отступы).
Т.е. нужно задать каждому **div** с классом ***item*** максимальную из их высот в текущем блоке ***row***.
Желательно через **jQuery**... Но приветствуются любые варианты!

Пробовал так:

```
 $('.item').height( $('.item').parent().children().filter('.item').height() + 'px' );
```

Но так устанавливается высота только для первого ***item***, и при том его собственная - т.е. ничего не меняется.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$('div.row').each(function(){
    var heights = [];    
    $('.item', this).each(function(){
        heights.push($(this).height());// заносим в массив высоты всех блоков
    });
    $('.item', this).height(Math.max.apply(null, heights));//находим и устанавливаем этот максимум 
});
```

**UPD:** обновил ответ

Comment: Спасибо, кажется принцип понял...
Немного изменил ваш код:

    $('.item').each(function(){
      var h = Math.max.apply(Math, $(this).parent().map(
            function(){return $(this).height();}).get());
      $(this).height(h + 'px');
    });

Comment: `o.height(h + 'px');` такая запись избыточна, можете не добавлять строку 'px', и зачем вам проходить по всем элементам, потом обращаться каждый раз к их родителю...а дальше я вообще запутался

Comment: Мне нужно найти максимальную высоту не всех ***div*** с классом **item**, а только среди тех из них что принадлежат одному ***div*** с классом **row** и назначить им эту максимальную высоту.

Comment: тогда измените селектор на `"div.row > .item"`

Comment: Не встречался с таким селектором, спасибо - буду изучать.

Answer (score 4):

```
$.fn.equalizeHeights = function() {
  var maxHeight = this.map(function(i,e) {
    return $(e).height();
  }).get();

  return this.height( Math.max.apply(this, maxHeight) );
};
```

Использование:

```
$('.item').equalizeHeights();
```

Менее затратно по ресурсам нежели обход с помощью `$.each`

Comment: >Менее затратно по ресурсам нежели обход с помощью $.each

по вашему `map` магическим образом делает меньше итераций?

Comment: Спасибо, **markuper**, хороший пример. Возьму на заметку.  
**Spectre**, т.е. вы хотите сказать, что *map* и *each* равны по скорости ?

Comment: в их основе лежаит циклы с одинаковым кол-вом итераций

Comment: Этот пример приведен в АПИ самого дж квери совместно именно с методом МЕП, поэтому считаю что использование меп в данном случае более разумно нежели each

Comment: т.е. вы признаёте, что "менее затратно по ресурсам" - это пустые слова?

Comment: Признаю что в команде дж квери работают хорошие специалисты, и пример с высотой блоков, они запихнули именно в map, а не в each